# Can Class attribute be an array

Tags: python

I'm new to OOP and python, so please bear with me if this is a simple question. If I create a class, which has attributes "a", "b", and "c", is it possible for the attributes to be an array, such that attribute a[2] has a meaning?

All answers I searched and found seems to be answering in wrong direction! So, I make it more explicit by the following lines, hopes it helps clarifying my question:

What I mean is, for example, the part: `breakfast=['menuitem2','menuitem3']` in the below lines:

```py
def main():
    menuitem1 = MenuItem()
    menuitem2 = MenuItem(title="Cocktail Bun", cost="8.0",long_desc="Cocktail Sweat Bun", short_desc="CB",item_type="bread")
    menuitem3 = MenuItem(title="Mexican Bun", cost="7.0",long_desc="Maxican Sweat Bun", short_desc="MB",item_type="dessert")
    menu1 = Menu()
    menu2 = Menu(breakfast=['menuitem2','menuitem3'],lunch=menuitem3,dinner=menuitem2)
    menu3 = Menu(breakfast=menuitem3,lunch=menuitem2,dinner=menuitem3)
    menus = [menu2, menu3]
```

How can I make it works? Would be many thanks for kind help!

Comment: Attributes can contain any object and a `list` (what you probably mean with "array" in Python) is an object.

Comment: If the class is not one you wrote, it's not up to you. Without seeing the documentation or code, it's impossible to say if a list would be allowed in that context.

Comment: Not sure what you want from your code.  do you mean:  `breakfastmenu = Menu(); breakfastmenu.add(MenuItem("cocktail bun",cost=8)); breakfastmenu.add(MenuItem("mexican bun",cost=7))`?  Which now means you have a breakfast menu with two possible options you can order?  That would be 2 classes, 1 for the Menu, 1 for the items.  And, yes, the menuitems could be stored in a `list` (Python's array type, more or less) within a menu instance.

Comment: Intuitively, I'd expect that even if your Menu class ate lists for breakfast, the items would be expected to be actual MenuItem references, not the string representations of variable names containing MenuItems.

Comment: Another way to explain it: you can pass any object anywhere and the interpreter will let you. But there interpreter also allows the receiving end to raise an error at any time.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding I think this will achieve what you are after.

The 2 changes I made to your definition was

- I removed the quotes round the breakfast list to use the defined objects
- I used lists for all of the menu attributes as I made the assumption that all would have multiple values.

One thing to note is that menu1 and menuitem1 are never used. I am not sure if this is intended or not.

Code:

```
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, title=None, cost=None, long_desc=None, short_desc=None, item_type=None):
        self.title = title
        self.cost = cost
        self.long_desc = long_desc
        self.short_desc = short_desc
        self.item_type = item_type


class Menu:
    def __init__(self, breakfast=None, lunch=None, dinner=None):
        self.breakfast = breakfast
        self.lunch = lunch
        self.dinner = dinner


def main():
    menuitem1 = MenuItem()
    menuitem2 = MenuItem(title="Cocktail Bun", cost="8.0",long_desc="Cocktail Sweat Bun", short_desc="CB",item_type="bread")
    menuitem3 = MenuItem(title="Mexican Bun", cost="7.0",long_desc="Maxican Sweat Bun", short_desc="MB",item_type="dessert")
    menu1 = Menu()
    menu2 = Menu(breakfast=[menuitem2,menuitem3],lunch=[menuitem3],dinner=[menuitem2])
    menu3 = Menu(breakfast=[menuitem3],lunch=[menuitem2],dinner=[menuitem3])
    menus = [menu2, menu3]

    print(menus[0].breakfast[0].title)
    print(menus[1].breakfast[0].title)

    print(menus[1].lunch[0].short_desc)

main()
```